# What is the type of this error Java.lang.Error

Tags: java

When executing this code:

```
    public class First_code {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            int i;
            i ++;
        }
    }
```

What is the type of this kind of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
     The local variable i may not have been initialized
     at First_code.main(First_code.java:6)
```

Is it a runtime error or semantic error?
Some sources say that a semantic error is is one in which the code uses a variable that isn’t initialized properly, does that make this error a sematic error?

Comment: One second on Google: *Semantic error: writing invalid program logic that produces incorrect results when the instructions are executed. The syntax of the source code may be valid, but the algorithm being employed is not.* Your program does not compile, it is thus more severe than a semantic error

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! But what is the type of error, I've searched a lot to find out if it's a runtime error or another sort or errors but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of error"? Are you trying to fix this or are you just interested about this error from a theoretical perspective?

Comment: Actually I'm asssessing my classmate work, he explained this kind of error as a semantic error, I know it's not, but I'm not sure what type it is, I'm still new in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you show is a runtime error.

The runtime error is telling you that you're trying to run code that failed to compile.

The code failed to compile because it's not legal Java.  That may be a syntax error or a semantic error; you'd have to study the language specification to be sure.  Semantic error is more likely, which means the grammar did not reject it -- which would have made it a syntax error -- but rather there's probably some wording in the spec around how you must initialize before use.

But that distinction between a compile-time syntactic error and a compile-tim semantic error is rather academic. Either way, the compiler says it's not legal Java.

Comment: The code that produced this error is the following:
public class First_code {
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  int i;
  i ++;
 }
}
Knowing that "the most common semantic error is one in which the code uses a variable that isn’t initialized properly." and i is not initialized, does that make it a semantic error?

Comment: @BasharSalman edit your question and put this code in the question, not just in a comment.